# A question about loadCollections() in Milvus

Tags: python, api, vector, methods

In the `loadCollection()` method, the first time I load four partitions (test1,test2,test3,test4), and the memory is full. Then I load a partition (test5) in the second time. Will the memory only contain the data from the newly loaded partition test5, or will the some data from the previous partitions (test1,test2,test3,test4) be swapped out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second suppose is correct. When the memory is full, calling `loadCollection()` will result in a data swap.